# Possible/safe to do some kind of onMeasure cacheing?

Tags: android, optimization, layout, android-layout

I have a lot of small views layered on top of each other in my current app, to the point where  Method Profiling says that Measuring, etc accounts for most of the cpu time for the general use of the app after set up.

Given that none of these views change size or position in their parent view, is it possible/safe to cache these somehow to save cpu cycles? On my Desire I see no delay, but apparently on users' Droid x's there is noticeable lag between clicking a view and the resulting screen update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measurement is already cached by the framework automatically as long as none of the child views are requesting a layout and the measurement parameters from the parent view are unchanged. Are you sure that the measure pass is what's slowing things down on these devices?

Comment: Turns out to have been a GC I manually kicked off. Had put it in back when there were bitmap loading related issues with heap filling up. Taken out now ;)